Closed form for $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-x^n}{1+x^n}$
I was reading "Theory of $H^p$ Spaces" by Peter Duren and, at one point (page 156), he is able to bound one infinite product from below by another of the form
\begin{equation}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-x^n}{1+x^n} 
\end{equation}
when $0 <|x|<1$, which he notes is greater than $0$ (which is easy to show). Does anyone know of any closed form expressions for this infinite product?

Outside my area of expertise. Wolfram Alpha says this product equals $\vartheta_4(0, x)$. See Wikipedia article on the theta function.

$$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-x^n)}{(1+x^n)}=\frac {\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x^n) }  {\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n) }$$
Using the  q-Pochhammer symbol
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x^n)=(x;x)_{\infty }$$
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n)=\frac{1}{2}(-1;x)_{\infty }$$ give
$$f(x)=2 \frac{(x;x)_{\infty }}{(-1;x)_{\infty}}$$
Have a look hereand here for the relations between Jacobi theta functions and products.
As @njuffa already commented $f(x)=\vartheta _4(x)$.
If you have any doubt, expand  as  series
$$f(x)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\,x^{n^2}=\vartheta _4(x)$$
